# Rails conditional layouts: Why does ":for" work as an option for the layout method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

In my controller I'm using `layout 'application', :only => :edit`

But I noticed that `layout 'application', :for => :edit` works as well.

Just curious because docs only mention `:only` & `:except`. I can't explicitly find `:for` in any docs for the `layout` method.

[Rails v2.3 - layout (railsapi.com)](http://railsapi.com/doc/v2.3.2/classes/ActionController/Layout/ClassMethods.html#M000264)

[Rails v3.1 - layout (apidock.com)](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Layouts/ClassMethods/layout)

Comment: When you say "works as well" do you mean that it **only** uses the `application` layout for your `edit` action but not for others? My guess is that it's completely ignoring your `:for` parameter and just using the `'application'` layout for all actions.

Comment: Ah... Thanks Dylan.  I think you're right.  I hadn't noticed that because the original developer was specifying additional conditional layouts.  But now I'm even further confused because these are listed `layout 'login', :except => :edit`  &  `layout 'application', :only => :edit`  but the show view is rendering neither the 'login' or 'application' layout.  There must be something defined elsewhere that I've not discovered yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I commented above, Rails is ignoring your :for parameter and should just be using the 'application' layout for all actions.

As far as rendering multiple layouts, it seems you can only have a single `layout ...` line for your controller; if you have multiples, it will only use the last one. And if the last one has an `:only` or `:except` parameter, it *should* fall back to the `application` layout for all the other actions. If it's not properly using the `application` layout and rendering without any layout whatsoever, make sure the previous developer didn't put something like `layout nil` somewhere in your controller/application.

If you want to handle multiple layouts inside your controller, you could also try this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  layout :choose_layout

  def choose_layout
    if action_name == "edit"
      "application"
    else
      "login"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Here's where I'm still confused...  When I do not specify a layout, it renders the 'application' layout, but if I add `layout 'login', :except => :edit` then a nil layout is rendered for :edit. Can't find `layout nil` or anything similar.  Any thing or where else you can think to look for such?